# UIViewController loadView method

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller

when overriding the loadView method in UIViewController, should one call [super loadView] in the beginning of the method or at the end of the method?  And why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to be really sure, you didn't mean viewDidLoad, right?  Because they are two very different methods... as of 3.0, the docs reccomend always calling viewDidLoad at the start.

You can call it either before or after, but usually it is placed at the end unless you have a reason to do otherwise.

Comment: Not sure why this is the accepted answer. While indeed correct, it doesn't answer the question asked.

Comment: Because being helpful is more important than being pedantic to the person asking the question.

Comment: I appreciate the helpfulness, Stack Overflow is nowhere without it. I'm just not sure why you did't put this as a comment. You're asking for clarification and then answering a different question. Neither of which makes it fit to be a candidate for an answer.

Comment: Fair enough, I thought the correction likely enough and the mistake common enough (confusing the terms) that it should be more prominent than a comment.

Answer (score 15):

According to the [UIViewController class reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html), you should not call `[super loadView]` at all:

> Your custom implementation of this method should not call super.

Comment: This is correct. However, the documentation quite clearly states that you use this method to create your view hierarchy, setting self.view to the base UIView. In which case - don't call [super loadView]. However, if you want to add subviews, then you can call [super loadView]; and then so something like [self.view addSubview:mySubview]; without any problems.

Comment: That's an important clarification, thanks Daniel. Although, I have always added my subviews in -viewDidLoad.

Answer (score 7):

Normally you should not call loadView directly. It merely sets your self.view property and is called by the view controller only.
You should call [super loadView] only if you need the view created by your super class, because you want to include it in your decoration view hierarchy or something like that.

Comment: When overriding `loadView`, you shouldn't call `[super loadView]`?  I just tried it and the result is that the view doesn't load, which is what I would expect.

Comment: @Nestor: The documentation states clearly "You should never call this method". You should however implement it correctly, i.e. you must set self.view in loadView.

Comment: It's like `dealloc`.  You should never call it yourself, but when you implement it, you should always call `[super dealloc]` at the end.  I typically call `[super loadView]` and have the base class handle creating the view, then add subviews myself.